# regular expression mysql search

Tags: mysql

i have the following values in my column table:

```
field_challenge_steps
field_challenge_steps.nid
field_challenge_steps.entity_view_prepared.nid
field_challenge_steps.entity_view_prepared.entity_view_prepared.nid
field_challenge_steps.entity_view_prepared.entity_view_prepared.entity_view_prepared.nid
nid
vid
und
body
```

How to write the regular expression in order the query return the following result:

```
field_challenge_steps.nid
field_challenge_steps.entity_view_prepared.nid
field_challenge_steps.entity_view_prepared.entity_view_prepared.nid
field_challenge_steps.entity_view_prepared.entity_view_prepared.entity_view_prepared.nid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE column REGEXP '^field_challenge_steps(\.entity_view_prepared)*\.nid$';
```

Comment: does not work for me, it will return "field_challenge_steps.aaa.nid". i don't need that. i only need records hat start with "field_challenge_steps" and end with ".nid" and between these two we can have "entity_view_prepared"

Comment: that is what i need Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment:

`field_challenge_steps(\.entity_view_prepared.?)?\.nid`

Demo http://rubular.com/r/HkbRGcfm8b

Comment: i want to have all that start with "field_challenge_steps" and end with ".nid" and between these two we can have "entity_view_prepared". so if i have: field_challenge_steps.aaa.nid - it should be ignored